# Many 403 failed to fetch errors and repository warnings when I try to run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am attempting to use Python on Ubuntu 20.04 on a virtual machine. I was trying to install pip, and used the instruction get-update, and a long series of errors appeared as below.

Does anyone know what the problem is and what can I do to fix it?
Thank you.

```
joseemallah@joseemallah:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Err:4 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP:
91.189.88.142 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP:
192.115.211.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP:
192.115.211.70 80]
E: The repository 'http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP:
192.115.211.70 80]
E: The repository 'http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Does running the same command again work? The software update mirror in your question is not down, so maybe a networking issue is occurring on your end.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to network issues, or issues with the current software server you are using. Try changing the server in "Software & Updates", "Ubuntu software" tab. You can change the the server in the dropdown next to "Download from:". If the error persist irrespective of the servers you select, then suspect your network configuration and connection.

Comment: The asker's current software server is not currently down, however there could have been a temporary network problem with that software server ~20 minutes ago that has been resolved.

Comment: @karel that is indeed my first suspicion, a connectivity issue.

Comment: Thank you for your replies Vanadium and @karel
If it is a connection problem, then this is getting hard to solve. In fact, I am connecting to a pc via AnyDesk, and on this pc, I installed Virtual Host to run ubuntu on it, and therefore, I am not able to actually connect to another network (unless there is a way I am not aware of).
Vanadium I did not know where to find the option to change servers that you mentioned, so if you could help me through with some  more details please.